# Turtle module in Python[3.8.5] not working

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code, pip, python-turtle

I'm using VS Code on Ubuntu, and am using the latest version of Python (3.8.5). I'm trying to import turtle but I got errors about module tkinter missing. I also installed it via command line as `apt install python3-tk` and got it successfully installed, but turtle doesn't yet seem to work at all. What am I missing?

Here's the short and simple code I've written in VS Code to check if it works or not:

```
import turtle
import tkinter

s = turtle.getscreen()
turtle.color('Blue')
n = 100 
turtle.forward(n)
```

After I try to run my code, a white window appears for less than a second and disappears again. So it's simply not working.
Here's what VS Code tells me:
[image]

Any helps will be appreciated :)

Comment: You said "I get errors about module tkinter missing". Can we please have a copy of these errors and also is there an error when you import just `tkinter` (ignoring `turtle` for a moment`)? It is slightly confusing that pylint is saying turtle does not have methods that it should do but hopefully we can figure out the cause.

Comment: @MinionJim I had that error before I installed tkinter, the error saying tkinter is missing no longer appears, but my code doesn't work yet, no window opening or anything. And no, there is no error regarding to tkinter ever since I installed it. The only errors I get is what you can see above in the posted pic :(

Comment: Thank you for giving that clarification (I obviously misread the question :-(  . Please try radding `turtle.done()` to the end of your code and see if that resolves your problem (this would explain the window flash you describe). For your reference, the information in the screenshot are not errors and are instead a piece of software called `pylint` giving you what it thinks are potential issues with the code. A lint doesn't say "there is a problem here" and is instead pointing out a potential problem for you to make the final decision (like a yellow line under code in other IDEs).

Comment: Sorry, ran out of characters. I think you may find it helpful just to read the pylint [docs intro](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html) as this explains a little about the project.

Comment: @MinionJim Thank you so much for your time :) I noticed the window appears when I type ```turtle.Turtle()``` instead of ```turtle.getscreen()```, besides, some codes I personally made sure they work on IDLE won't work on VS Code for me, but some do! I wonder if this is regarding to the version or some changes to the module... I don't dare blame VS Code for this... it shouldn't have such a flaw!

Comment: If you were on MacOS I would venture so far (see [Python issue 41574](https://bugs.python.org/issue41574) message 375643 onwards) but you would assume it uses the system Python install. Regardless, I am glad you have resolved your problem.

Comment: @MinionJim I appreciate your patience and clear instructions, thanks so much :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no error with the package installation, try this

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
```

this would create a window

```
t.forward(100)
turtle.done()
```